ML Project Question - Non-deterministic cost function
I'm hoping to run a ML gradient descent analysis to help tune a multi step non-deterministic simulation with 15 or so parameters. The simulation function is non-deterministic because it contains a lot of noise (RNG being used many times). This aspect of the function cannot change as it's meant to simulate a real life scenario where a lot of randomness exists (specifically a basketball game). Based on my basic understanding, it seems to be a problem that could be solved with some type of least squared analysis / loss minimization given a large enough training sample. However, I'm not quite sure given the non-deterministic nature of the simulation.
Is it possible to tune the parameters in this function using a stochastic gradient descent (or something similar?) so that the function better fits the real life training data I have? My primary worry is that the cost function will have to be non-convex / non-deterministic because of the randomness in the base function.
If this seems like a bad idea, I would love to hear about any other suggested methods for this problem. Happy to provide more details if necessary :)

Adding on - could using a random.seed fix this problem?
